Input Parameters for Combustion Chamber
I am doing a column breakup study. But for a better study I need air velocity, turbulence intensity (not primarily needed though),temperature, pressure and same parameter for injected liquid fuel. I searched for an commercials but there is no useful information. Could you help me with the sources ? Thank you in advance.

I am not sure of what your question is.  Are you looking to model a breakup/atomization of a stream of fuel or oxidizer from a rocket injector?  For a typical face-injector fuel and oxidizer streams are designed to impinge each other instigating breakup. For a pintle injector such as SpaceX uses that was developed from the LEM Descent Engine of Apollo different atomization strategies are used. Most development work was done experimentally.  Theoretical models are in the literature. There are probably thousands of published studies into this subject.

For a general purpose jet engine,general  fuel and crossflow parameters was what I looked for. For level flight. But as you these combustion chamber parameters are not easy to find. And experimental studies are limited on temperature and velocity for both phases.
